# Camcorder for use as a webcam

Tags: hardware, usb, firewire, camcorder

I've been looking into a camcorder for use as a webcam, since all the webcams I have found don't seem to be up to the task I have in mind.

My biggest issue is finding camcorders can can even be used as a webcam, either natively or through a 3rd party software such as [DVDriver](http://www.clearptz.com/TCamWeb/dvdriver.htm). DVDriver requires that the camera have an IEEE 1394 port, but it seems that this is not a common thing on camcorders now like it was years ago.

Capability to record in 1080p and a wide angle lens would also be useful.

Does anyone know of any camcorders that are capable of this, or a resource where I can find more information on camcorders?  My searches of the Sony, Canon and other manufactures websites has turned up very little in the way of useful information.

Comment: Hey, I am running into the same problem. Did you find any resolution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to come to a resolution on this one.  After researching it quite a bit I found that it was going to be too expensive and too much hassle to be able to get a camcorder setup as a webcam, so I abandoned the project. The biggest issue I had was that without actually purchasing everything and trying it, I had no way of knowing if anything would actually work as expected. Seems this method of recording fell out of favor about 5-7 years ago. Kinda surprising given the lack of high quality webcams.

Comment: Well, i just bought stuff from best buy. Plan to return it if things dont work :-). I am begining to figure things out. will update this post once i do.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how it goes, if you figure something out that works make sure to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know one solution, but it's not cheap as webcams. Same time full hd quality is something that webcams usually doesn't deliver.
Device especially interesting for live shows recording and streaming.

http://zoom.co.jp/products/q2hd

Webcam driver is provider by Zoom, so you still can use it as regular webcam delivering high quality video and audio to Skype for instance.

PS: there are plenty of reviews on youtube.

Comment: I'll have to check that out in the future. Definitely appears to beat any webcam I'd looked at in the past, and it seems simple enough to connect.  All the old methods I had researched required tons of conversion. Thanks for the link.